# Mutiple tables using loop in html template without or with javascript with same with everything same as e created this table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, bootstrap-4

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">#</th>
<th scope="col">First</th>
<th scope="col">Last</th>
<th scope="col">Handle</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">1</th>
<td>Mark</td>
<td>Otto</td>
<td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">2</th>
<td>Jacob</td>
<td>Thornton</td>
<td>@fat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">3</th>
<td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
<td>@twitter</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a table i am using, i want to create same multiple tables using for loop in html code without javascript and i am using bootstrap in my html code 
can anyone help me how to do that

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to achieve but if the goal is to create **dynamically** table rows based on some data structure, you can't achieve that with HTML alone...

Comment: You cant do a loop for inside HTML without javascript, because you need to change the DOM so HTML does not provide this option

Comment: My point is i have this table and i want n number of  tables like this with some dynamic data then how can get to that.

Comment: If using javascript,  then how to create same table like this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're missing some things in your HTML. You open a `<head>` tag, but close it with a `</body>` tag, which doesn't make sense. You need a closing head tag and an opening body tag.

HTML is a markup language. This means it only describes how the webpage looks, there are no for loops in HTML.

So, you'll need to use a different language to display tables with a loop. Javascript can do it client-side (or server-side if you're using node.js), and a language like C#.Net or PHP will do it server-side.